# Rails 4: nested attributes not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a stupid problem, but I can't figured out what the cause of it. Nested attributes of model not saving

poll.rb

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :poll_options
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :poll_options

  validates :name, presence: true

end
```

poll_option.rb

```
class PollOption < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :poll

  validates :name, presence: true

end
```

polls_controller

```
      def new
        @poll = Poll.new
        @poll.poll_options.build
      end

      def create
        @poll = Poll.create(poll_params)
        if @poll.save
          redirect_to poll_path(@poll)
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end

      private

      def poll_params
        params.require(:poll).permit(:name, :description, poll_options_attributes: [:id, :name])
      end
```

view

```
= simple_form_for @poll do |poll|
  = poll.input :name
  = poll.input :description
  = simple_fields_for :poll_options do |option|
    = option.input :name
  = poll.button :submit
```

What did I miss? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `poll.simple_fields_for`, not just `simple_fields_for`.